# I can't connect a service that is inside a docker container to a mongodb database that is in another docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

i have 2 containers, the first container has a microservice called "authentication" and the second has a mongodb database. I'm trying to connect the first container to the second and it doesn't work. the 2 are executed but I cannot connect one with the other. My operating system is Windows 11. I am attaching images of the docker-compose, the dockerfile and the .env of the microservice.

.Docker-compose file (this file is located in a separate folder from the "authentication" microservice)
`

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  authentication:
    build: ../authentication
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      PORT: 8080
      MONGODB: mongodb://localhost:27017/emprendamos

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:6
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGODB_DATABASE: emprendamos
    volumes:
      - ./mongo:/data/db
```

`

.env file of the "authentication" microservice
`

```
PORT=8080
MONGODB='mongodb://localhost:27017/emprendamos'
```

`

.Dockerfile of the "authentication" microservice
`

```
FROM node:18.12.1

WORKDIR /authentication

COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

CMD [ "node","dist/main.js" ]
```

`

I expect to be able to establish the connection of the container that has the microservice with the container that has mongodb inside

Comment: localhost doesnt work here. Each container is its own host.

Comment: ok so, what should i replace that with and in which file?

Comment: with the container name or network alias. i.e. mongodb